# How to test and call batch class in Apex class?

Tags: apex

```
global class batchExample implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id,Name FROM Account';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> accList) {
    for(Account acc : accList){
        acc.Name = acc.Name + 'Webkul';
    }
    try {
        // Update the Account Record
        update accList;

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.debug(e);
    }

}   

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this question?

Comment: I am Salesforce QA, i am not able to explain the code details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click here for more info](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch)

```
@isTest 
 public class AccountUpdateBatchJobTest{
    static testMethod void testMethod1(){
    List<Account> lstAccount= new List<Account>();
    for(Integer i=0 ;i <20;i++){
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name ='Name'+i;
        lstLead.add(acc);
    }

    insert lstAccount;
    Test.startTest();
        batchExample obj = new batchExample();
        DataBase.executeBatch(obj,20); 
    Test.stopTest();
}
}
```